# Hybris Update issue - azure.abstractbundler6307sn table doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to run Update using HAC but getting exception:

Caused by: **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException**: Table '**azure.abstractbundler6307sn**' doesn't exist

When I checked my schema, this table is created under 'hybris' schema, there is no schema 'azure'. Why am I getting this error?

My **local.properties** file has following configurations for MySQL:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hybris?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useFastDateParsing=false
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.username=root
db.tableprefix=
db.password=root
mysql.optional.tabledefs=CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
mysql.tabletype=InnoDB
mysql.allow.fractional.seconds=true
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share with us, the Stacktrace and the item schema ?

Comment: Did you check "Update running system"?

Answer (score 0):

Other issue is incompatibility between hybris version and mysql server version, so this applies to local installations.